# Swift Login enter MySql

Tags: mysql, swift, xcode6

Can't figure it out how to do this:

I have a login form ( no need to register ) which have 2 field. When the user write in this field and push "Login" button the app check in the web mysql database if there is the field, if yes go next page if not print the error message. My problem is to pick the informations from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a webservice to query an external database like MySQL in this case. Your app should have a way to collect the iphone input for login and then send the data to an api to query and return the result of the request to the iphone.

Comment: do you think this tutorial can help me? https://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2014/07/login-signup-screen-tutorial-xcode-6-swift-ios-8-json/

Comment: @VaultDesign yes I'd say so. Ray Weinderlich also has a lot of tutorials. Just google his name